# How to compare and filter files in the directory with filename in text file or excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, script, mp3, development

I have 100000 mp3 files in one directory, each file contain a random filename , and I have another excel sheet containing the mp3 file's name and to whom it maps to.
Is there any way to develop a script or 3rd party software can help categorize these files into 3 different folder

Example:

- In the directory

File such as : fasf4a5465.mp3, fasdf35434.mp3, vefbgwsbgg.mp3

- In the Excel

  1. Column 1: File name =  fasf4a5465.mp3, Column 2 'File Group' =  Group1
  2. Column 1: File name =  fasdf35434.mp3, Column 2 'File Group' =  Group2
  3. Column 1: File name =  vefbgwsbgg.mp3, Column 2 'File Group' =  Group3

So my final output will be three different folders (Group 1, Group2, Group3), the 100000 will be categorized as per excel sheet mapping

Since I have many Mp3 files it's hard to listen for each of them and categorize them manually, so I need somehow a way to compare and place them in different location

Any workaround for that ?

Comment: For clarity. You already have the exact file names in a list and it names the group you want it in. Correct? So if I asked you to make three lists, copy and past group1 into a notepad file and save it as group1.txt all the names in that list would be for your desired folder, yes? Can you copy and past an excel spreadsheet for a better understanding of what there is to work with? The solution might be to create a formula to separate the list into several distinct lists and then use programming to create folders and move them into said folder.